# How can I set the current_timezone in DB2 V8.1 database server?

Tags: linux, timezone, db2, sys

Is there a way that I can SET the current_timezone in DB2 database ? By querying

```
db2 "select current timestamp , current timezone from sysibm.sysdummy1"
1                          2       
-------------------------- --------
2015-05-13-22.02.23.714464       0.
```

Right now my Current_Timezone value is 0 , so it is set to GMT but I want to manually set it to PST (-80000).

**Can you please guide me the steps to do that ?**

Answer (score 1):

The DB2 database manager obtains time information from the operating system, so you'd need to set the time zone via the `TZ` environment variable for the instance owner, then restart the instance.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. I am looking for the list of timezone values in DB2 v8.1 (for eg : GMT is 0 , PST is -80000) but I am not able to find that anywhere.  Can any one point me to that ?